# Position error messages (alerts) in the bottom right corner using Bootstrap and CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show some error messages, let's say

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show col-12" role="alert">
        This is an error
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show col-12" role="alert">
        This is an error
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
```

Stacked in the bottom right corner of the screen, using HTML, CSS, Bootstrap
Just like this[Image of messages in the bottom right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwfaS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an error wrapper div and position it absolute.
eg.

```css
.error-container{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <div class="error-container">
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show " role="alert">
      This is an error 1
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show " role="alert">
  This is an error 2
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```